# Is there a book that cross-references where the names of animals are mentioned in Tana"ch?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, tanach, animals

I was impressed with the Jerusalem Biblical Zoo, as it had a verse that mentioned the name of the animal. Is there a book that simulates this idea, i.e. a book that quotes the verse of all the different animals mentioned somewhere in Tana"ch?

Comment: I think Prof. Feliks's book (I think it's called _Hatzomeach V'hachay Shebamishna_) does so for _mishnayos_, but not for _Tanach_.

Comment: @sh210 Prof. Feliks has a similar book for Tanakh, called חי וצומח בתורה, which has been translated into English

Comment: @magicker72, now part of it is.

Comment: @msh210 Indeed, the wild animals volume was released earlier this year, and is excellent.

Comment: https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/בעלי_חיים_בתנ%22ך

Answer (score 1):

*[The Torah Encyclopedia of the Animal Kingdom](https://books.google.com/books?id=OpdnrgEACAAJ&dq=the%20torah%20encyclopedia%20of%20the%20animal%20kingdom&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFzrzD5ofgAhWsV98KHc74DswQ6AEIKDAA)* by [R. Dr. Natan Slifkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natan_Slifkin) seems to be exactly what you are looking for. It contains a chapter on each of 26 animals, filled with verses that mention the animals as well as statements of the Sages about the animals. It also has lots of other information, plus it has plenty of high quality photographs accompanying each animal.

You can read the chapters on the leopard and the hyrax for free, [here](http://www.zootorah.com/assets/media/LeopardLayout.pdf) and [here](http://www.zootorah.com/assets/media/HyraxLayout.pdf).

Comment: Note that this is only the first volume of a planned multi-volume work.